# Android Edittext Drawable click stuck focus

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have three edittext on one layout. When it's empty, then I remove the right drawable. When it isn't empty, I added the drawable. When you click to drawable, I clear the edittext.

When I clicked to rightdrawable, the cursor was stuck, and underline stay colored. Rarely I have a 2-3 cursor. Why?? What I do bad?

BAD:
[image]

GOOD:[image]

The Layout:

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

The MainActivity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private DrawableState etstate1;
private DrawableState etstate2;
private DrawableState etstate3;
private EditText et2;
private EditText et1;
private EditText et3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
    et3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);


    etstate1 = new DrawableState(et1);
    etstate2 = new DrawableState(et2);
    etstate3 = new DrawableState(et3);

    et1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (DrawableClick.isDrawableClick(motionEvent, et1, DRAWABLE_RIGHT)) {
                et1.setText("");
                etstate1.refreshDrawable();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    et2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (DrawableClick.isDrawableClick(motionEvent, et2, DRAWABLE_RIGHT)) {
                et2.setText("");
                etstate2.refreshDrawable();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    et3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (DrawableClick.isDrawableClick(motionEvent, et3, DRAWABLE_RIGHT)) {
                et3.setText("");
                etstate3.refreshDrawable();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            etstate1.refreshDrawable();
        }
    });

    et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            etstate2.refreshDrawable();
        }
    });

    et3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            etstate3.refreshDrawable();
        }


     });

    }
}
```

Helper classes:

```
public class DrawableClick {


    public static boolean isDrawableClick(MotionEvent event, EditText editText, DrawablePositions drawablePosition) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (editText.getCompoundDrawables()[drawablePosition.position] != null && event.getX() >= (editText.getRight() - editText.getLeft() - editText.getCompoundDrawables()[drawablePosition.position].getBounds().width())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    public enum DrawablePositions {
        DRAWABLE_LEFT(0),
        DRAWABLE_TOP(1),
        DRAWABLE_RIGHT(2),
        DRAWABLE_BOTTOM(3);

        private int position;

        DrawablePositions(int pos) {
            this.position = pos;
        }
        }
    }
```

Next:

public class DrawableState {

```
private EditText editText;
private Drawable[] editTextDrawables;

public DrawableState(EditText editText) {
    this.editText = editText;
    saveDrawableState();
    refreshDrawable();
}


public void saveDrawableState() {
    this.editTextDrawables = editText.getCompoundDrawables();
}

public void refreshDrawable() {

    if (editText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        editText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
        editText.clearFocus();
    } else {
        if (editTextDrawables != null) {
            editText.setCompoundDrawables(editTextDrawables[0], editTextDrawables[1], editTextDrawables[2], editTextDrawables[3]);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Change it

```
       if (DrawableClick.isDrawableClick(motionEvent, et3, DRAWABLE_RIGHT)) {
               ...
                return true;
            }
            return false;
```

To:

```
  if (DrawableClick.isDrawableClick(motionEvent, et3, DRAWABLE_RIGHT)) {
            ...
            motionEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        }
        return false;
```